# RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap

Tags: android-fragments, canvas, bitmap

I have a card view which has a custom adapter and it loads image into its target using Picasso(inside onBindViewHolder(lazy load) ).
The custom row has a button on which when clicked  opens fragment which displays image in wide view , Using the bitmap from original imageview
( before in fragment i check if bitmap is loaded fully in main imageview  using  a boolean in callback of Picasso to 'true' in onSucess() . till then my button is disabled )   like :

```
                BindViewHolder:

                Picasso.with(context)
            .load(cl.getUrlPhoto())
            .resize(500, 500)
            .error(R.drawable.images)
            .into(cardViewHolder.urlPhoto, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    cardViewHolder.imgL=true;
                    cardViewHolder.fab.setEnabled(true);
                    cardViewHolder.pb_b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    cardViewHolder.imgL=false;
                    cardViewHolder.fab.setEnabled(false);
                    cardViewHolder.pb_b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

(i check here for the boolean to be true then do this part of code  )Fragment part where it loads :

```
              imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
              Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache(true);
              BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)                                  
              imageView.getDrawable();                
              bitmap1 = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
              scaleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
```

. But Sometimes on scrolling when the images are still loading or loaded  or  just clicking to view full image 2-3 times it crashes and gives  error

"  RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap . "

Answer (score 0):

This exception is raised in situations where you try to recycle or set to null an image which is loaded by **Picasso** which means the **Picasso** library does not expect the image loaded by it to be recycled and when it tries to load that an exception is thrown. hope this solution works for you

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing Picasso with Glide

Comment: This is too short...you had explained it better